# Pick Up the latest version from Maven Repository

Tags: maven, unix, scripting

I have one Maven repository and in that repository we have different folders with folder name like:
1.11
1.21
1.31
1.41
2.11
2.43
So from these versions I need to pick up the latest version using script and then I need to use the :
wget http://maven.com/m2/sm/tools/wls/which we get using script/wls-which we get using script.jar
unzip wls-which we get using script.jar

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do (really)? Why using wget instead of Maven?

Comment: There is a Maven Repository and from that Repo I need to get the latest jar and unzip that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `dependency:unpack` goal of the maven dependency plugin

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/unpack-mojo.html

to download and unpack a dependency with Maven. In most cases it is not good to grab " the latest" version, but set the version explicitly. Otherwise, you get non-reproducible results when the version changes.